What are Bitcoin clients, servers, nodes and peers
People often refer to some software as a Bitcoin client.
People often refer to Bitcoin nodes.
People sometimes talk about connections to peers.
What are these things? How do they differ? What is the right term?

Peer (Node)
A node is a peer in a peer-to-peer network. The idea here is that all peers have the same role and responsibilities. Their roles are not differentiated.

Source
Client
A client typically is a type of participant or role in a distributed application structure called client-server. Clients communicate with servers and not with other clients.

Source
Servers primarily communicate with clients and not with other servers. When servers communicate with other servers they might use a different protocol (e.g. SMTP instead of IMAP/POP) or otherwise act as a client instead of as a server in that relationship.

Bitcoin
The Bitcoin network was designed as a peer-to-peer network. Not as a client-server network.
Bitcoin core
Strictly speaking, calling a program such as bitcoin-qt a client is misusing client-server terminology for peer-to-peer distributed-application structure.
bitcoind is a server (for the RPC API) but note that bitcoin-qt isn't a client for bitcoind at present.
bitcoind and bitcoin-qt are both nodes or peers with respect to the peer-to-peer Bitcoin network protocol. Both are servers (not clients) with respect to the network-accessible client-server RPC API. bitcoin-cli is a client for that.
See related question about constituent programs of Bitcoin Core

I agree that in a strict sense, nodes in a P2P system shouldn't be referred to as "clients" (due to confusion with the meaning that term has in client-server architecture), but it does appear to be a common name regardless. For example, just see the name of this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients
